# Jenkins Gitlab multi-branch concurrent builds

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

Anyone has idea how to limit number of concurrent builds on Jenkins for multi-branch pipeline?
I was searching out but almost every approach was about putting `properties([disableConcurrentBuilds()])` which doesn't work in my case.

We use resource lock for unit tests, so they don't overlap. In my case no matter how many build executors I have they will just wait on lock to be released so they continue one by one while reserving build slot instead waiting in queue. I found some similar post:

[Jenkins limit multibranch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754119/limit-jenkins-concurrent-build-only-for-specific-branches)

Answer (score 0):

for gitlab pipelines use parameter *resource_group* for create a resource group that ensures a job is mutually exclusive across different pipelines for the same project:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#resource_group

for jenkins: plugin and parameter "Block build if certain jobs are running"
https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-blocker-plugin/